# Unable to listen to default close button of a Dsektop window

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js, desktop-application

I am developing a windows desktop application using `node.js` and `backbone.js`. I want to perform an action when the user closes the app by clicking on the close button on the title bar or right clicking on the application from windows taskbar.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what node-desktop technology are you using- if you are using node-webkit, then [this comment on this pull request](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/issues/322#issuecomment-11982546) gives some indication of how to use the API bindings for the windowing system to do something like this.